# Cannot find Main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle

I'm having issues regarding Java being able to find my main class of a LibGDX game.  I'm working with other people, all of whom have been able to set up the project correctly and run/build the game on their computers.

The project structure looks something like:

```
love-pirates
    core
        src
            com.pirates.game
                LovePirates.java
    desktop
        src
            com.pirates.game.desktop
                DesktopLauncher.java
```

When I try to run the DesktopLauncher.java, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pirates.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher
```

When I try to build through Gradle, I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol 
import com.pirates.game.LovePirates;
                       ^
symbol:   class LovePirates
location: package com.pirates.game
```

Here is my build.gradle in the desktop module:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.pirates.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

And my build.gradle in core module:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

Even if I export as a JAR and try to run it on a different machine, I'll get the main class not found.  So it can sometimes compile to completion (0 warnings, 0 errors) and yet not run correctly.

I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA 15 on OSX using jdk 1.8.0_65.  I'd be happy to supply any more needed information.
Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit 0:** Here's the path to my compiled DesktopLauncher:

```
love-pirates/desktop/build/classes/main/com/pirates/game/desktop/DesktopLauncher.class
```

Comment: If your program is properly build then you will be able to find DesktopLauncher.class file. Give the directory structure where .class file is present and I'll help further

Comment: Can't really help for IntelliJ IDEA, but for Android Studio I always have to create a new run command for Desktop since only the android run command is present. Specify the module as the desktop module, then when assigning the main.class it automatically finds `DesktopLauncher` for me. For the working directory I always use `android/assets` but this is more of a personal thing since you can specify another asset folder for each module.

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty: Added the path to my .class file; see edit #0!

Comment: @MennoGouw: I have created a different run configuration for the desktop module, since the android module is empty right now.  Are there any other options you've set in the configuration manager?

Comment: In command prompt goto navigate till classes/main/ directory and then run this command without qoutes 'java com.pirates.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty: Same error ("Error: Could not find or load main class com.pirates.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher").  And yet if I "cd com/pirates/game/desktop/" then "ls", DesktopLauncher.class is right there.

Comment: Sorry navigate till desktop directory and run the same command..it should definitely work

Comment: Navigate till the directory where .class file is present and run the above command as it is

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, and it produces the same error - I've tried both the reverse-domain before the class and just the classname.

Comment: Does your DesktopLauncher class have a main method in it?

Comment: Yes, there's the standard main method in DesktopLauncher, which is why I'm so confused.